# Wordpress Plugin , Event Registration page list all events in a select box

Tags: wordpress

Is possible to do a event registration page like this page with any wordpress plugin.?
http://www.mtcentr.ru/registratsiya-v-trening/. (Register with: line. 6th line).

I want to select one event from that event list and proceed to checkout.

I am ready to purchase premium  wordpress plugin.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin name Plugin Registration, it seems to fit your needs: http://wordpress.org/plugins/event-registration/

Comment: I'm checked that plugin. but I can't find that option (all events dropdown list in a registration form). please help...